# Square-integrable, uniformly continuous and vanishing at infinity implies bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If a function $f(x)$ satisfies the following:

1) $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$,

2) $f'$ exists everywhere, $f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}f=\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}f'=0$,

3) $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Is there enough there to show that $f$ is bounded? If so, how?

Comment: Just continuity and $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)$ exists are enough to show that $f$ is bounded.  Take a large $M$ and examine $f$ on $|x| \geq M$ and $|x|\leq M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick an $x_{0}$ such that $|f(x_{0})|>0$. The condition $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$ implies that there is some $M>0$ such that $|x|\geq M$ entails that $|f(x)|<|f(x_{0})|$, then $|f(x)|\leq\max\{\max_{|x|\leq M}|f(x)|,|f(x_{0})|\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need all this hypothesis to show that.

$f$ bounded since $\lim_{|x| \to \infty}f(x)$ exists and is a real number and $f$ is continuous since it is differentiable.